# Find invariant points under matrix transformation (degeneracy)

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, invariance

> I have the matrix
>
> $$Q=\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\0&1\\\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> and want to find the invariant points.

To do this, I solve the equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\0&1\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\\end{bmatrix} $$

The first equation is $-x + 2y = x \Rightarrow y = x$. This shows that any points on $y=x$ are invariant under the transformation represented by $Q$.

The second equation, however, gives $y = y$ which encodes nothing? Just **interested in the origin of this degeneracy and whether it has any significance**...

---

Further question prompted by an answer:

Sometimes when I solve the matrix equation, the first and second equation both give the condition. In this case only the first equation gives $y=x$ and the second equation is degenerate. In what cases would I have both equations leading to the same condition or one being degenerate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q$ has rank $2$ and eigenvalues $+1$ and $-1$. The invariant points correspond to the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $+1$. As you have found, these are scalar multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\end{bmatrix}$ and so lie on the line $y=x$.

The eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$ are scalar multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\end{bmatrix}$ and so lie on the line $y=0$. In other words, points on the $x$ axis are reflected in the $y$ axis.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Q$ then $\det(Q-\lambda I) = 0$, in other words $Q-\lambda I$ is degenerate. So when you solve $(Q - \lambda I)X=0$ to find the eigenvector for a given eigenvalue, the final row of $(Q-\lambda I)X$ is always redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The non-zero invariant points are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$. If the problem has full rank, then the only solution would be the zero vector.

As you have shown, the only condition is $x=y$. That is, the invariant points are multiples of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: Sometimes when I solve the matrix equation, the first and second equation both give the condition. In this case only the first equation gives $y=x$ and the second equation is degenerate. In what cases would I have both equations leading to the same condition or one being degenerate?

Comment: If you only have the zero vector as the invariant solution, then both equations will be independent. However, if there are non-zero invariant solution, then $1$ is an eigenvalue and the matrix $Q-I$ has to be singular, then you will only have one condition and the solution will be a multiple of a non-zero vector.

Comment: $Q$ is not singular but has non-zero invariant solution: $detQ = -1 \neq 0$?

Comment: $Q-I$ is singular. $Qx=x \implies (Q-I)x = 0$.